# aiogram || Как доабвить формулу в бота?

Tags: python, aiogram, callback, конечные-автоматы

**Здравствйте. Пишу бот на aiogram. Хочу сделать так, чтобы после нажатия инлайн-кнопки, пользователь ввел значения, которые бот обчислит по формуле:**

*A = int(input("Длина: "))
B = int(input("Ширина: "))

area = A * B;

print("Площадь прямоугольника: ", area)*

**Как это сделать после нажатия инлайн-кнопки? Буду благодарен.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тебе код. Только не забудь наделать проверок на входящие данные, а то тебе текста кинут и бот исключением тебя одарит

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class MathInput(StatesGroup):
    num1 = State()
    num2 = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton('Площадь квадрата', callback_data='math_start'))
    await message.answer("text", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="math_start")
async def math_start(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.answer("Введи первое число")
    await MathInput.num1.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=MathInput)
async def get_num(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if (await state.get_state()).split(":")[1] == 'num1':
            data['num1'] = message.text
            await message.answer("Введи второе число")
            await MathInput.num2.set()
        else:
            num1 = float(data['num1'])
            num2 = float(message.text)
            await message.answer(f"Площадь равна {num1 * num2}")
            await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Огромное.